# How to cast object to another where base is 'higher'?

Tags: c#

There are two classes. Class B dervied from A.

```
class A
{  }

class B  : A
{  
    public B()
    {  

    }
    public int Number { get; private set; }
}
```

This gives me the error 'unable to cast from A to B'.

```
void Test()
{
    var a = new A();
    var b = (B)a;     // <== unable to cast.
}
```

How can I cast the object in variable A to class B?

Thank you.

Comment: It's like saying here's a fruit, make it an apple.

Comment: @Shaded: Oh man, did you seriously leave that comment before I posted my answer? Now I feel like a thief...

Comment: @Dan Tao YEAH YOU JERK! lol, I just didn't leave an answer cause there were plenty of people with acceptable answers and I just like fruit. :D:D:D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code fails because you don't have a B.

You could do it if you created a B instead of an A:

```
A a = new B();
B b = (B)a;
```

You could think of A as `Animal` and B as `Bear`.

You can always say a bear is an animal, but if all you've got is an unknown animal you can't always cast it into a bear. That works only if it actually *is* a bear.

Comment: +1 For providing a solution instead of saying "you can't". :) Further, @robertpnl, notice the use of the derived class B *in place* of an instance of the parent class. This has some [important implications.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: +1 This is the only answer that is actually a possible solution

Comment: +1 for the succinct analogy, along with any further elaboration posed.

Answer (score 8):

Put simply, you can't - `B` is an `A` but `A` is not a `B`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't - A is *not* a B.  Plain and simple.

Answer (score 2):

You can't case a base class into its derived class. You can the other way around though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. What you *can* to is to provide a constructor in `B` that takes an `A` as argument, and create a new `B` instance based on that:

```
class B : A
{
    public B() { }

    public B(A original)
    {
        // copy values from original to this
    }

    public int Number { get; private set; }

}
```

Then you can do like this

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't - a is an A, it is not a B.

Answer (score 0):

Let's replace `A` and `B` to hopefully make the impossibility of this a bit clearer:

```
class Fruit
{ }

class Apple : Fruit
{ }

class Banana : Fruit
{ }

// If what you wanted to do were possible...
Fruit f = new Apple();

// ...then this should be possible (but how does one magically transform
// an apple into a banana?)
Banana b = (Banana)f;
```

Comment: You should note in your example that apple and banana extend fruit.

Comment: You forgot to have `Apple` and `Banana` extend `Fruit`

Comment: @Shaded: You are very correct. @SwDevMan: Yes, yes I did. (Whoops!)